# button only open blank tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new here. i'm trying to run my script to open a new page. but the result is, it only open a new blank page. can someone please help me to solve this?

```
<form method="get" action="/specials/test-page-only">

    <button class="btn btn-label btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">

        <label><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-2x"></i>

        </label>Reshare This Special</button>

</form>
```

script i use;

```
     var myNodelist = document.querySelectorAll(".btn.btn-label.btn-block.btn-lg.btn-primary");
     var TotalNewLink = 0;
     var TotalOldLink = 0;

     for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) 
     {
         if (myNodelist[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Reshare This Special") != -1) 
         {
             TotalOldLink += 1;
         }
     }

     chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
         type: 'TotalOldLink',
         text: TotalOldLink
     });

     for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
         if (myNodelist[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Reshare This Special") != -1) {
             window.open(myNodelist[i].href, '_blank');
         }
     }
```

Comment: The `myNodeList` elements do not seem to have an href..

Comment: Please post your HTML as code not image

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the `href` attribute on the `<button>` element:

```
window.open(
    myNodelist[i].href, // <-- this returns undefined
    '_blank'
);
```

But the button doesn't have an href attribute, so you are getting a blank URL instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.href = url` instead of `window.open(myNodelist[i].href, '_blank');`
But if you are not going to use the method i told, try to look if there is a href property on myNodelist